# Integral Inequality from unit interval to reals with $f$ and $f'$

Tags: calculus, integral-inequality

For continuously differentiable function $f : [0, 1] → R$ with $  f  \big( \frac{1}{2} \big)  = 0$, show that
$$
\left(\int_0^1 f(x) dx\right)^{2} \leq  \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1  (f' (x))^{2}dx
$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where is this from?

Comment: It's from Imperial College Math Competition. I've thought about integration by parts, cauchy-schwarz, proving a stronger equality etc. fairly standard stuff. It may be susceptible to one of the aforementioned methods but I just haven't been able to do it.

Comment: I would probably try some form Taylor's Theorem, but I'm not sure it works yet.

Comment: I also thought about MVT but it didn't seem promising at all

Comment: This is a standard exercise for integration by parts / calculus of variation. What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Could you post a solution please as I'm not familiar with calculus of variations.